# In SQL, how to split timestamps into several intervals but with the first record of the day as the beginning of the first interval?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

**PostgreSQL 9.5**

My dataset looks like this:
[image: Sample data]

---

I want to split the records of the same day into a 1-minute interval, but with the beginning of each interval as the min value of the interval.

With this dataset, my ideal output would look like this:
[image: Output]

For example, in 2014-05-27, the min value is 15:09:40, so the first one-minute interval would be `15:09:40 - 15:10:40`, and there're three records. For the next interval, `15:11:01 - 15:12:01`, there's one record.

Hope I have made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use CTE or subquery to get a gap_seconds which represents a value from subtracting of `occurred_at` and previous `occurred_at` of row, then making an grp column to calculate values that hold the gap.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           FLOOR(SUM(gap_seconds) OVER(ORDER BY occurred_at) / 60) grp
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
               EXTRACT(SECOND FROM  occurred_at - LAG(occurred_at,1,occurred_at) OVER(ORDER BY occurred_at)) gap_seconds
        FROM T
    ) t1
)
SELECT MIN(occurred_at) occurred_at,
       COUNT(*)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c67ff8d6492c30ce937c06c8e5983be8)

another example, we can division by 120 second like this below query

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           FLOOR(SUM(gap_seconds) OVER(ORDER BY occurred_at) / 120) grp
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
               EXTRACT(SECOND FROM  occurred_at - LAG(occurred_at,1,occurred_at) OVER(ORDER BY occurred_at)) gap_seconds
        FROM T
    ) t1
)
SELECT MIN(occurred_at) occurred_at,
       COUNT(*)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e0fe2096e2c3ce57ae2e324d631ceb18)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is what I'm looking for. For your dummy table, the first interval is `15:09:40 - 15:10:40`. There're 3 counts. That's correct. But for the next interval, which is `15:10:55 - 15:11:55`, there should be 2 counts, including `15:11:01`. But in your output, `15:11:01` is a separate row. Thanks anyway!:)

Comment: Following your train of thought, I'm wondering is there anything we can do using something like `SUM(gap_n_occurred_at) OVER (PARTITION BY XX ORDER BY occurred_at)`? So that as along as the running total of `gap_n_occurred_at` exceeds 60s, 120s, etc, we know there should be a new interval.

Comment: @ericzheng0404 I had  edit my answer you can try it

Comment: @ericzheng0404 `that as along as the running total of gap_n_occurred_at exceeds 60s, 120s, etc, we know there should be a new interval.` I edit my calculating way you can modify your own interval in `FLOOR` function which is the denominator.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. BTW can you edit your answer with `GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', occurred_at'), grp`? so those for different days having the same time they're in different intervals. Just want to make sure people, if any, having the same question can get exactly the right answer. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I was reviewing your query. Your second example, the one divided by 120, is returning two-minute interval, right?